# What's better in this context? "one more line" or "another line"?

Tags: word-choice

In order to draw something two dimensional, we are doing two steps: 1)  drawing one line. 2) We add another line to this line.

B.t.w. if you think that I need to improve another thing in this paragraph, kindly let me now of that.

Comment: This is getting close to proofreading. There is little if any meaningful difference between *another line* and *one more line* in your context.

Comment: How could I know that? :) English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: How could I knew that :) For my point of view, one of them could be a mistake. English is not my mother tongue. And as much as I know, this site is also for whom English is not his mother tongue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The two words are not 100% identical in meaning and nuance.**

"One more" is used for an action done to finish something.

e.g.

> One more point and I win!

(the thing to be finished is the game)

> Cut one more piece of wood.

(the thing to be finished is the cutting to get pieces of wood)

"Another" is for something to happen again; or a repetition. e.g.

> He lost another hat in the river.
>
> You must fight another enemy.

**Also, "one more" can be used to bring more emphasis onto the one more thing added to some count.**

> I won't allow one more bandit in!

This implies that a significant amount of bandits had already came over in the past, and the speaker doesn't want yet another one.

> I won't allow another bandit in!

This signifies that at least one bandit came in and the speaker doesn't want this to happen again.

**However there are contexts where "one more" and "another" *can* mean the same thing.** e.g.

> "Another slice of cake please!", "One more slice of cake please!"

Comment: For me, the only difference is "one more" emphasizes the number, while "another" does not. It's like the difference between "One slice of cake" and "Another slice of cake". So for example "He lost one more hat in the river" sounds weird, but only because it oddly emphasizes the number of hats he has lost.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi You're the downvoter? (Don't worry - I'm not mad, I just was hoping a troll didn't pass by) I'm fixing now.

Comment: Another point and I win!

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce what you say a little: "In order to draw something two dimensional, we draw a line and then add a line to it."

If you really want to keep the "two steps" construction, it would be better to say: "In order to draw something two dimensional, we do two steps: 1) draw one line, 2) add a line to the first line."

Any of these imply that the second line is being drawn in a way to add it to the first line, i.e., that the two lines are related.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to ask you as a pupil to his teacher, why did you used "draw" (present simple) rather that "drawing" (regarding to the steps)

Comment: Correction: rather than*

Comment: Writing tends to be easier to understand with action verbs "(we) draw" and "(we) add".  To say "1) drawing one line" is not right, because "we" is already the subject of the sentence. And "to draw" is the infinitive, it is also incorrect to use "drawing" there.